# Repeated Measures ANOVA using PROC GLM and trying to compare treatment groups across time with an estimate statement but getting an error message

Tags: sas

I am doing a repeated measures anova using a PROC GLM and getting an error message of the following.

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a numeric constant, a datetime constant,*.
ERROR: Variable Control not found.
```

I am unsure of why it is not finding this. I am trying to add estimates for each of the groups by each other.

CODE

```
Title 'Repeated Measures ANOVA';
PROC GLM DATA=Volumeday;
CLASS Group;
MODEL Day11 Day15 Day18 Day22 Day25 Day29 Day31 = Group/ nouni;
REPEATED Volumes 7 (11 15 18 22 25 29 31) Contrast (1);
Estimate 'Control vs 50' Group Control 50;
RUN;
```

DATA

```
Group   SingleID    Day11   Day15   Day18   Day22   Day25   Day29   Day31
Control 1   18.3265 123.9459    277.5853    469.2007    786.0575    1200.4905   2157.7883
Control 2   8.9600  132.4787    272.9526    291.9831    358.5270    552.6809    831.4478
Control 3   30.3888 27.9484 32.9774 57.2910 102.3590    158.7149    264.3438
Control 4   152.3057    177.8362    237.3441    333.7665    541.3562    807.9747    1322.6820
Control 5   75.8382 210.9038    288.8744    526.7819    1177.8997   1495.5090   1983.0081
Control 6   109.4968    261.4477    646.6212    1045.1347   1409.9562   2100.0035   3606.0111
Control 7   69.7455 140.1223    545.3165    865.7220    1074.2843   4817.3938   5062.0829
Control 8   27.5759 140.4200    179.4372    208.1606    214.3055    244.5793    375.6873
Control 9   69.9840 278.3642    665.7404    948.2510    1291.2181   1773.4409   2526.5430
Control 10  0.0000  5.1754  28.6286 55.9888 85.3166 130.3152    228.2616
Control 11  58.3283 98.3813 250.7581    320.7870    498.5181    786.6884    1092.7527
Control 12  76.8369 213.3508    310.6329    687.7342    1158.0864   1816.7347   2468.0657
Control 13  83.2098 171.3893    494.8624    1279.0689   1586.3263   2146.5180   3179.8413
50  14  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
50  15  70.5439 289.3574    319.6232    605.7606    767.8226    1195.2030   1285.2694
50  16  56.6206 204.2804    209.3167    316.0949    874.6215    1058.7214   1066.0440
50  17  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
50  18  54.0136 260.7759    379.6304    598.2225    834.9887    1623.1321   1960.1044
50  19  0.0000  88.0999 158.8836    478.2094    594.5207    679.1422    785.5714
50  20  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
50  21  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
50  22  67.6676 176.2211    486.8332    671.0626    1510.1275   2288.6294   2493.2663
50  23  0.0000  92.0981 615.5709    942.8944    774.2735    1121.9150   1158.6388
50  24  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
50  25  0.0000  2.5323  2.0644  19.9026 44.7534 57.3573 61.9292
50  26  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
100 27  51.1564 112.6072    238.5177    560.8209    665.5958    1001.8340   1086.0031
100 28  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
100 29  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
100 30  31.9500 87.1252 95.7135 198.5657    631.4217    902.2800    1016.0448
100 31  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
100 32  0.0000  0.0000  5.6459  20.7742 59.5984 49.7367 94.8133
100 33  30.3624 179.8866    274.3788    410.4248    946.3005    1318.0000   1504.2507
100 34  0.0000  0.0000  25.1096 88.5573 145.3025    324.4817    476.9385
100 35  0.0000  41.6587 62.3404 102.9104    164.9199    179.5294    394.4932
100 36  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
100 37  0.0000  1.3099  1.7978  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
100 38  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
100 39  0.0000  12.9966 43.6856 207.1046    277.0362    430.6310    504.4368
200 40  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 41  53.2928 462.4648    695.2788    1064.9500   1172.7716   1270.2056   1507.2874
200 42  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 43  30.1754 151.9196    438.3676    353.3577    422.8638    460.1100    606.3912
200 44  12.1342 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 45  68.1526 113.8426    340.2685    706.1297    831.9715    1073.0574   1276.5542
200 46  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 47  16.2057 50.2423 100.9858    248.5628    339.0762    368.7926    660.4432
200 48  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 49  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 50  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 51  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
200 52  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
```

[image: Some of the Data]

Comment: Please replace the picture of you with the data in TEXT format then we can copy to use in testing.

Comment: How do I do that? When I try to paste from excel or sas it doesn't work.

Comment: Pasting data from a text file, like a SAS program, is going to work better than pasting from EXCEL as that will include TAB characters instead of spaces between the values in a row.  To make the pasted text not be flowed into paragraphs tell SO it is code. Just highlight lines and press Crtl-K to insert 4 spaces at the start of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be to correct syntax.  Again post data as TEXT and I will be able to test.

```
Estimate 'Control vs 50' Group 1 -1;
```

Comment: @Priscy you need to look it up because it is too much for me to explain.

Comment: thank you! Based off of that I edited my code to
PROC GLM DATA=Volumeday;
CLASS Group;
MODEL Day11 Day15 Day18 Day22 Day25 Day29 Day31 = Group;
REPEATED Volumes 7 (11 15 18 22 25 29 31) Contrast (1);
Estimate 'Control vs 50' Group 1 -1 0 0;
Estimate 'Control vs 100' Group 1 0 -1 0;
Estimate 'Control vs 200' Group 1 0 0 -1;
Estimate '50 vs 100' Group 0 1 -1 0;
Estimate '50 vs 200' Group 0 1 0 -1;
Estimate '100 vs 200' Group 0 0 1 -1;
RUN;         However, now it is showing the estimates by day and not overall. Is there a way to show that?